# NameError : name 'pass_result' not defined line 25?

Tags: python, html, cgi, nameerror

Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="coach.css" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" width="74" height="64"><strong><img src="images/logo-cel-transparent_0.png" alt="Cel logo" width="74" height="64" align="right">
</strong>
<h1 align="center"><strong>Central Electronics Limited</strong></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2 align="center">Storage Management System</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">Login To System</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<form action="cgi-bin/validate.py" method="post">
  <div align="center">Username :
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password :
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

validate.py:

```
import cgi
import yate
import sqlite3
import sys


connection = sqlite3.connect('users.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()


print('Content-type:text/html')
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
for each_form_item in form.keys():
  if (each_form_item=='username'):
    username=form[each_form_item].value
  if (each_form_item=='password'):
    password=form[each_form_item].value

result=cursor.execute('SELECT USERNAME from validate')
usernames=[row[0] for row in result.fetchall()]
print(usernames)
for each_username in usernames:
    if (username==each_username):
        pass_result=cursor.execute('SELECT PASSWORD from validate where username=?',(each_username,))
    password1=[row[0] for row in pass_result.fetchall()]
    for each_password in password1:
        if (each_password==password):
            with open("C:\Python34\ProjectShivam\webapp\cgi-bin\successvalidate.py") as f:
              code = compile(f.read(), "successvalidate.py", 'exec')
              exec(code) 

        else:

            print('')
            print('Login Failure')
```

successvalidate.py:

```
import yate


print(yate.start_response())

print(yate.para("Login Successful"))
print(yate.include_footer({"Click here to Go to Welcome Page":"/welcome.html"}))
```

simple_httpd.py(The server code):

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8080

httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Starting simple_httpd on port: " + str(httpd.server_port))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I run the server(simple_httpd.py) using command prompt. The index page opens up. I enter the 1st set of username and password. It runs as expected and successvalidate.py opens up. But when i enter the 2nd set of username and password(i.e, the second row of table validate in users.sqlite)(validate table contains two set of usernames and passwords), it displays on cmd:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2015 20:59:29] b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  F
ile "C:\\Python34\\ProjectShivam\\webapp\\cgi-bin\\validate.py", line 25, in <mo
dule>\r\n    password1=[row[0] for row in pass_result.fetchall()]\r\nNameError:
name \'pass_result\' is not defined\r\n'
```

Also any other username does not result in the text 'Login Failure' being printed on the web browser but instead same error shows on server. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting the error when this condition is not met:

```
if (username==each_username):
    pass_result=cursor.execute('SELECT PASSWORD from validate where username=?',(each_username,))
```

set a default value to pass_result, e.g. `pass_result = None` and then handle it before using, e.g. `if pass_result is not None:`